# Adobe Lightroom starts automaticaly

Tags: windows-7, adobe-lightroom

Every time I insert a SD card into my computer, Adobe Lightroom starts and tries to import images from the card. How do I stop this?

I use Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change autoplay options for your SD card.

Go to `Control Panel` > `Devices and Sounds` >  `Autostart options`. Under `Images`, instead of importing with Lightroom, choose `Ask me every time`. CLick `Save`, and that's all.